# CodeIgniter Routing / Htaccess / URI issues

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

I recently joined a team of devs and I'm trying to get an SVN checked out onto my local machine.  Unfortunately, I've run into some issues with links and routing.  My local machine is using a WAMP setup.

Let's say I have in my controller:

```
function testfunc()($this->load->view('testfunc');
```

and in my testview view I have

```
<li><a href="<?=site_url('testfunc')?>">what we do</a></li>
```

At first, I was getting a URL disallowed characters issue.  Thumbing through some threads, I added in rawencode($str) and some other things.

Now I get a 404 Page Found error, when the files are clearly there.  It appears as though my controller isn't being called, and in turn the view is not called

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Going to what URL results in a 404 error?

Comment: Going to the testfunc url which maps to localhost/testfunc results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the controller. Unless you are using some sort of routing, you should be using something like:

```
<li><a href="<?=site_url('controller/testfunc')?>">what we do</a></li>
```

OR

```
<li><?php echo anchor('controller/testfunc', what do we do);?></li>
```